# Domain Events for syncing data to other microservices

Tags: domain-driven-design, dddd

I am trying to learn more about `DDD` and was going through the `DomainEvents`. Let's say we have three microservices `Service A`, `Service B` and `Service C`.

`Service A` has an entity `Foo` defined as below:

```
public class Foo : AggregateRoot
{
    public string id {get; private set;}

    public string name {get; private set;}

    public string email {get; private set;}
}
```

and the `Service B` is a service that depends upon the `email` from `Foo` while the `Service C` depends on the `name` from `Foo` and the data is replicated from `Service A` to `Service B` and to `Service C` whenever there is a change in the values of `Foo` via a `Bus`.

**Guidelines about Domain Events that I came accross:**

1. Do not share excess information as part of the `DomainEvent` data.
2. When `consuming BoundedContext` knows about `Producing BoundedContext` maybe share the Id otherwise share full information
3. Don't use `DomainClasses` to represent data in Events
4. Use `Primitive types` for data in `Events`

Now the question that arose due to conflicting guidelines:

> Does it mean that I should fire two different events when they change like `FooNameChange` and `FooEmailChanged` and only use the `id` along with the `updated value` as part of the `Event Payload`?

Or can I just make a single `DomainEvent` called `FooChanged` and take the state of the `Foo` serialize it and fire the event. Then write up a handler as part of the same `BoundedContext` that would take the data and drop it on the `Bus` for any service subscribed to the message and the individual service decides on what actions to take based on the `Id` that was attached and the event arg (*the updated data*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to talk across services, you should be perhaps looking for Integration Events instead of "Domain Events"
From Microsoft [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/domain-events-design-implementation)

> Domain events versus integration events
>
> Semantically, domain and
> integration events are the same thing: notifications about something
> that just happened. However, their implementation must be different.
> Domain events are just messages pushed to a domain event dispatcher,
> which could be implemented as an in-memory mediator based on an IoC
> container or any other method.
>
> On the other hand, the purpose of integration events is to propagate committed transactions and updates to additional subsystems, whether
> they are other microservices, Bounded Contexts or even external
> applications. Hence, they should occur only if the entity is
> successfully persisted, otherwise it's as if the entire operation
> never happened.
>
> As mentioned before, integration events must be based on asynchronous communication between multiple microservices (other
> Bounded Contexts) or even external systems/applications.
>
> Thus, the event bus interface needs some infrastructure that allows
> inter-process and distributed communication between potentially remote
> services. It can be based on a commercial service bus, queues, a
> shared database used as a mailbox, or any other distributed and
> ideally push based messaging system.

What information you send within the integration events, it really depends. You have the following choices:

- Publish the event such as `FooNameChanged`, `FooEmailChanged` with only `Id` of `Foo`. In that scenario, if your consumers need further information of *what* has changed, they would need to make a call your service (perhaps a REST API call). A disadvantage of this approach is that if you have many subscribers to your event then all those services would call your service to get the details of the event almost at the same time.
- Publish the event with the full data (note that it is not same as your Domain) which a consuming service may need such as `PerviousValue`, `CurrentValue`, etc. If your payload is not huge, this can be a good option. These types of events are typically called "FAT events"

Answer (score 0):

`DomainEvents` are not patch documents.

Which is to say, we aren't trying to create general purpose descriptions of changes, but instead to align our messages with the concepts of our domain as we understand them.

So whether two changes belong in the same event, or in different events, gets a big "it depends".